# web services in Sharepoint

Tags: web-services

I want to host a web service in sharepoint 2013 to upload xml documents and then consume it. I know how to do it in a pure .Net web app, how can I host it in Sharepoint 2013?
maybe is only a sharepoint 2013 app?

Comment: SharePoint 2013 already support what you ask for on different ways, such as WebDAV, REST and CSOM. Why would you make a service which replaces built in functionality?

Answer (score 0):

You can deploy you web service in Sharepoint under "_vti_bin" folder.

The following article help you in deploying your service in sharepoint:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms464040.aspx